# Check whether a norm is linear functional.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given a function $f: \Bbb R^3 \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)= \|x \|$ determine whether it is linear functional.

First the closure property was checked i.e. the additive and scalar multiplication.The scalar multiplication property is satisfied but the additive property is violating the triangle inequality law hence it is not linear functional.

Is it not linear functional and whether the approach is correct.

Comment: You are right, norm is not additive.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Got it Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is not a linear functional and no, the approach is not correct. It is not true that $f(\lambda x)$ is always equal to $\lambda f(x)$. Just take any $x\neq0$ and $\lambda=-1$.

Comment: @ Jose Carlos Santos But one of the scalar properties of norm has the scalar to be taken as modulus when taking the scalar out

Comment: Indeed. And therefore$$\lVert(-1)\times x\rVert=\lvert-1\rvert.\lVert x\rVert=\lVert x\rVert\neq-\lVert x\rVert.$$

Comment: It is called a sublinear function. See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublinear_function

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Sorry my bad Got it Thanks

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Thanks